# How to use aggregate in the set list of an UPDATE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Let me describe the whole situation: I have below two tables. The values of `MaxTestCasesExecutedBySingleUser` and `TotalTestCasesExecutedByAllUser` in `Module` table needs to be updated using some Aggregate clause

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Module](
    [ProjectID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ModuleID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ModuleName] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [MaxTestCasesExecutedBySingleUser] [int] NULL,
    [TotalTestCasesExecutedByAllUser] [int] NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ([ProjectID],[ModuleID]))

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ModuleMember](
    [ProjectID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ModuleID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SerialNo] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ([ProjectID],[ModuleID],[SerialNo]))

Insert Into Module Values (1,1,'Installation_Test',null,null)
Insert Into Module Values (1,2,'Server_Test',null,null)
Insert Into Module Values (1,3,'Client_Test',null,null)
Insert Into Module Values (1,4,'Security_Test',null,null)

Insert Into ModuleMember Values(1,1,0,'Jim')
Insert Into ModuleMember Values(1,1,1,'Bob')
Insert Into ModuleMember Values(1,2,0,'Jack')
Insert Into ModuleMember Values(1,2,1,'Steve')
Insert Into ModuleMember Values(1,2,2,'Roy')
Insert Into ModuleMember Values(1,2,3,'Jerry')
Insert Into ModuleMember Values(1,3,0,'Root')
Insert Into ModuleMember Values(1,3,1,'Tom')
Insert Into ModuleMember Values(1,4,0,'Evil')
```

There is another Table Valued Function `dbo.GetValue` which takes `Name` (from `ModuleMember` table) as parameter and returns the values of `Name` and `TestCasesExecutedByTheUser`  in the form of a  table. I need to update these two values in `Module` table.

**Definition:**

MaxTestCasesExecutedBySingleUser = maximum number if test case executed by a member in a module

TotalTestCasesExecutedByAllUser = total number of test cases executed by all member in a module.

I tried below query but it is throwing me error : `An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement.`

```
UPDATE M
SET 
M.MaxTestCasesExecutedBySingleUser = MAX(N.TestCasesExecutedByTheUser),
M.TotalTestCasesExecutedByAllUser = SUM(N.TestCasesExecutedByTheUser)
FROM Module M 
JOIN ModuleMember Mem ON (M.ProjectID = Mem.ProjectID AND M.ModuleID = Mem.ModuleID)
CROSS APPLY dbo.GetValue(Mem.Name) N
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's perfect case to use [apply](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

```
update Module set
    MaxTestCasesExecutedBySingleUser = C.maxtc,
    TotalTestCasesExecutedByAllUser = C.sumtc
from Module as M
    cross apply (
        select
            max(N.TestCasesExecutedByTheUser) as maxtc,
            sum(N.TestCasesExecutedByTheUser) as sumtc
        from ModuleMember as MM
            cross apply dbo.GetValue(MM.Name) as N
        where MM.ProjectID = M.ProjectID and MM.ModuleID = M.ModuleID
    ) as C
```

Answer (score 4):

The workaround is a little more verbose - you have to get the aggregates first (e.g. in a CTE), and *then* update the target table:

```
;WITH src AS
(
  SELECT 
    Mem.ProjectID,  
    Mem.ModuleID,
    mtc = MAX(N.TestCasesExecutedByTheUser),
    stc = SUM(N.TestCasesExecutedByTheUser)
  FROM dbo.ModuleMember AS Mem
  CROSS APPLY dbo.GetValue(Mem.Name) AS N
  GROUP BY Mem.ProjectID, Mem.ModuleID
)
UPDATE M
  SET M.MaxTestCasesExecutedBySingleUser = src.mtc,
      M.TotalTestCasesExecutedBySingleUser = src.stc
FROM dbo.Module AS M
INNER JOIN src 
ON M.ProjectID = src.ProjectID 
AND M.ModuleID = src.ModuleID;
```